# FileUpload always return null value when button is clicked

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload, import

I have this page with FileUpload element. But when I try to get the value in the code behind, it always return "NULL" value. It's only happening in one page. The other pages works perfectly. What seems to be the problem? I tried searching but nothing works. Like using UpdatePanel, Triggers, etc.

Below is my code:

ASPX

```
<telerik:RadWindow ID="showImportDialog" runat="server" Skin="<%$ appSettings:Skin %>" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" 
Width="350" Height="200" Behaviors="Close" Modal="true" VisibleTitlebar="true" Title="<%$ Resources:Master, Import%>">
<ContentTemplate>
    <div class="inputField">
        <p style="font-weight: bold; padding-bottom: 3px;"><asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Master, SelectImportFileLbl %>" /></p>
        <div class="uploadFile">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-import"></span>
              <span class="filename fontSize13"><asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Master, ImportFieldText %>" /></span>
              <asp:FileUpload ID="ImportFile" runat="server" CssClass="fontSize13" ClientIDMode="static"/>
        </div>
        <p id="errorMsg" style="color: #FF0000; font-size:11px; display: none; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-top: 5px;">
            <asp:Label ID="Label5" ClientIDMode="static" runat="server" Text=""/>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="importGroup" class="delete-confirm-button" style="padding-top: 20px;">  
        <asp:Button ID="BtnImport" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" enabled="false"
                    EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" 
                    Text="<%$ Resources:Master, Import %>" ClientIDMode="static" />
        <asp:Button ID="BtnImportCancel" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" enabled="true"
                    EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" OnClientClick="btnCancel_Click('showImportDialog'); return false;"
                    Text="<%$ Resources:Master, Cancel %>" ClientIDMode="static" />
    </div>
</ContentTemplate>
</telerik:RadWindow>
```

VB

```
Protected Sub BtnImport_Click(sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles BtnImport.Click
    Dim fileName As String = String.Concat(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ImportFile.PostedFile.FileName), "_", DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmssff"), ".", Path.GetExtension(ImportFile.PostedFile.FileName))
    Dim filePath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine("DataImport", fileName)

    Dim fInfo As System.IO.FileInfo = New System.IO.FileInfo(filePath)
    fInfo.Directory.Create()

    ImportFile.SaveAs(filePath)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `Page_Load` method, I think the controls are getting reinitialized there. Wrap the code that you don't want to reinitialized with `If Not Page.IsPostBack Then`

If your original code within `Page_Load` is like this..

```
Sub Page_Load(..)
Line1 
Line2
...
End Sub
```

Then change it to the following:

```
Sub Page_Load(..)
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then     
        'Regular flow, keep the code
        Line1 
        Line2
        ...
    Else 
        'PostBack code, do not reinitialize 
    End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already checked the Page_Load. When clicking the import button, it goes to IsPostBack. Does that mean, it is reinitializing there?

Comment: You can try this... 
If your exising code within Page_Load is ```x,y,z.. ```, then simply move that within the If Not Page.IsPostBack method...


```If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
    x
   y
z
        Else
'keep this else portion empty
        End If

Comment: I tried your suggest but still no luck.

Comment: Please see my edited answer...

Comment: It did not work. :(